# Versioning image sprites in a git repository

Tags: image, git, versioning, sprite

Imagine this scenario:

We have a massive repository, with many different features branches. Each of the feature branches uses one large sprite image. This large sprite image might be slightly different in each feature branch. Feature branches might be merged into different release candidate branches, and then back into master, at different points.

Git cannot version this image (eg, merge changes to the image), and so we are struggling to find an approach to manage this.

One approach is to always keep a 'master' PSD of the sprite image. Whenever a new image is needed to be added to the sprite, a developer would first update the PSD master document, then export the new sprite image. This will ensure the sprite image will always contain all changes. But obviously this sprite image will contain changes we might not want in the different branches (eg, a change to an image within the sprite).

Essentially we need to be able to version this sprite image. Git is not the tool to help us with this, but we need the image to be versioned with the code.

How does one generally manage versioning of images in a git respository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't check in the compiled sprite image; instead, check in the individual images and programmatically build the sprite.  [Sprite Factory](https://github.com/jakesgordon/sprite-factory) is a tool I've successfully used in the past to build sprite sheets out of individual images.  It says it's intended for CSS use, but it can easily provide sprite offsets and dimensions for uses outside the web too.

Comment: I've come around to agree with you that this is the best approach. I'm looking into http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/

Comment: I've had some weird experiences with Compass sprites and the asset pipeline in Rails where images wouldn't update the way you'd expect them; that's why I recommended Sprite Factory.  But that was fall of last year, and so things may be better now -- or you might not even be using Rails.

Comment: We're not using Rails, but are using Compass. If Compass builds the sprites as documented, then it will fit in very nicely with our dev work-flow.